# record types with collection properties & collections with value semantics

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

In c# 9, we now (finally) have record types:

```
public record SomeRecord(int SomeInt, string SomeString);
```

This gives us goodies like value semantics:

```
var r1 = new SomeRecord(0, "zero");
var r2 = new SomeRecord(0, "zero");
Console.WriteLine(r1 == r2); // true - property based equality
```

While experimenting with this feature, I realized that defining a property of a (non-string) reference type may lead to counter-intuitive (albeit perfectly explainable if you think it through) behaviour:

```
public record SomeRecord(int SomeInt, string SomeString, int[] SomeArray);

var r1 = new SomeRecord(0, "test", new[] {1,2});
var r2 = new SomeRecord(0, "test", new[] {1,2});
Console.WriteLine(r1 == r2); // false, since int[] is a non-record reference type
```

Are there collection types with value semantics in .Net (or 3rd party) that may be used in this scenario? I looked at ImmutableArray and the likes, but these don't provide this feature either.

Comment: I like to think of records as structs. i.e. they should contain only value types

Comment: It's not a matter of reference types, it's whether the type implements `Equals` in term of its contents or not

Comment: If you check the generated code in Sharplab.io you'll see that even for `string`, Equals uses `EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals`

Comment: Records are not value types, they are classes with value semantics (much like string). They should contain only properties of types with value semantics (other records, structs, string, and potentially collections with value semantics - if these exist)

Comment: Value semantics for a general purpose collection type could be incredibly expensive - if they're at all generic they have no way of enforcing that their values have value semantics, so you're pretty well looking for a specialized type that will work for *your specific scenario*, not a general purpose type.

Comment: Looking [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netcore-3.1), the only "collection" type I see is `ImmutableArray<T>`, which as you've found doesn't have value semantics. Only `ValueTuple` does, but it's not really a collection type. If you do roll your own type, consider making it immutable or else you'll have a tough time implementing a correct `GetHashCode`.

Comment: While the below answer provides a way of solving the issue of value-based equality, this question has really made me question whether the inclusion of collections within a structure violates the very definition of record.  If a record isn't a flat data structure, it would seem to lack distinction from any ole class hierarchy, right?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It looks like there is currently no such type available.

You can implement this yourself, but beware of the implications if you need this in a production-ready way. It's not so simple as it may seem at first sight, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69840868/20047) by @ryanholden8 demonstrates!

For my use case (and as a simplified example) I went along with [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jhgbrt/4bf2cf7e5c077f7326c8b82160a9c59a) which decorates an IImutableList and can be used as follows:

```
var r1 = new SomeRecord(0, "test", new[] { 1, 2 }.ToImmutableList().WithValueSemantics());
var r2 = new SomeRecord(0, "test", new[] { 1, 2 }.ToImmutableList().WithValueSemantics());
Console.WriteLine(r1 == r2); // true
```

Obviously beware of the performance implications for very large lists.

Answer (score 9):

Our team faced a similar problem and started implementing based on the idea from @jeroenh. However, we ran into the issue of records that could no longer be deserialized from json with `System.Text.Json`. [Here's the gist](https://gist.github.com/ryanholden8/5602a6cc6decebb5bb35e21aa37efa67) (posted below as well) with everything we had to create in order to support this deep equality on records.

### ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace System.Collections.Immutable
{
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter(typeof(JsonConverterForImmutableArrayWithDeepEqualityFactory))]
    public struct ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> : IEquatable<ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T>>, IEnumerable, IEnumerable<T>
    {
        private readonly ImmutableArray<T> _list;

        public ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality(ImmutableArray<T> list) => _list = list;

        #region ImmutableArray Implementation

        public T this[int index] => _list[index];

        public int Count => _list.Length;

        public ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> Add(T value) => _list.Add(value).WithDeepEquality();
        public ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items) => _list.AddRange(items).WithDeepEquality();
        public ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> Clear() => _list.Clear().WithDeepEquality();
        public ImmutableArray<T>.Enumerator GetEnumerator() => _list.GetEnumerator();
        public int IndexOf(T item, int index, int count, IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer) => _list.IndexOf(item, index, count, equalityComparer);
        public ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> Insert(int index, T element) => _list.Insert(index, element).WithDeepEquality();
        public ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> InsertRange(int index, IEnumerable<T> items) => _list.InsertRange(index, items).WithDeepEquality();
        public int LastIndexOf(T item, int index, int count, IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer) => _list.LastIndexOf(item, index, count, equalityComparer);
        public ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> Remove(T value, IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer) => _list.Remove(value, equalityComparer).WithDeepEquality();
        public ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match) => _list.RemoveAll(match).WithDeepEquality();
        public ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> RemoveAt(int index) => _list.RemoveAt(index).WithDeepEquality();
        public ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> items, IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer) => _list.RemoveRange(items, equalityComparer).WithDeepEquality();
        public ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> RemoveRange(int index, int count) => _list.RemoveRange(index, count).WithDeepEquality();
        public ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> Replace(T oldValue, T newValue, IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer) => _list.Replace(oldValue, newValue, equalityComparer).WithDeepEquality();
        public ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> SetItem(int index, T value) => _list.SetItem(index, value).WithDeepEquality();
        public bool IsDefaultOrEmpty => _list.IsDefaultOrEmpty;

        public static ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> Empty = new(ImmutableArray<T>.Empty);

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => (_list as IEnumerable).GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() => (_list as IEnumerable<T>).GetEnumerator();

        #endregion

        #region IEquatable

        public bool Equals(ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> other) => _list.SequenceEqual(other);

        public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> other && Equals(other);

        public static bool operator ==(ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T>? left, ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T>? right) => left is null ? right is null : left.Equals(right);

        public static bool operator !=(ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T>? left, ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T>? right) => !(left == right);

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return _list.Aggregate(19, (h, i) => h * 19 + i!.GetHashCode());
            }
        }


        #endregion
    }

    public static class ImmutableArrayWithDeepEqualityEx
    {
        public static ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> WithDeepEquality<T>(this ImmutableArray<T> list) => new(list);

        public static ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> ToImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list) => new(list.ToImmutableArray());
    }
}
```

### ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality JsonConverter

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace System.Collections.Immutable
{
    public class JsonConverterForImmutableArrayWithDeepEqualityFactory : JsonConverterFactory
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
            => typeToConvert.IsGenericType
            && typeToConvert.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<>);

        public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            var elementType = typeToConvert.GetGenericArguments()[0];

            var arrayType = typeof(JsonConverterForImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<>);

            var converter = (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(
                arrayType.MakeGenericType(elementType),
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
                binder: null,
                args: null,
                culture: null)!;

            return converter;
        }

        private class JsonConverterForImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> : JsonConverter<ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T>>
        {
            public override ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
            {
                if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
                {
                    throw new JsonException();
                }

                reader.Read();

                List<T> elements = new();

                while (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
                {
                    var value = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader, options);

                    if (value is not null)
                    {
                        elements.Add(value);
                    }

                    reader.Read();
                }

                return elements.ToImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality();
            }

            public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<T> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
            {
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value.AsEnumerable(), options);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace System.Collections.Immutable
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonConverterForImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEqualityFactory))]
    public class ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue> : IEquatable<ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable, IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> where TKey : notnull
    {
        private readonly ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary;

        public ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality(ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary) => _dictionary = dictionary;

        #region ImmutableArray Implementation

        public TValue this[TKey index] => _dictionary[index];

        public int Count => _dictionary.Count;

        public ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue> Add(TKey key, TValue value) => _dictionary.Add(key, value).WithDeepEquality();
        public ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue> AddRange(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> pairs) => _dictionary.AddRange(pairs).WithDeepEquality();
        public ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue> Clear() => _dictionary.Clear().WithDeepEquality();
        public ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Enumerator GetEnumerator() => _dictionary.GetEnumerator();
        public ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue> Remove(TKey key) => _dictionary.Remove(key).WithDeepEquality();
        public ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue> RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TKey> keys) => _dictionary.RemoveRange(keys).WithDeepEquality();
        public ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue> SetItem(TKey key, TValue value) => _dictionary.SetItem(key, value).WithDeepEquality();
        public bool IsEmpty => _dictionary.IsEmpty;

        public static ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue> Empty = new(ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Empty);

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => (_dictionary as IEnumerable).GetEnumerator();
        IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator() => (_dictionary as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>).GetEnumerator();

        #endregion

        #region IEquatable

        public bool Equals(ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue> other) => _dictionary.SequenceEqual(other);

        public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue> other && Equals(other);

        public static bool operator ==(ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue>? left, ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue>? right) => left is null ? right is null : right is not null && left.Equals(right);

        public static bool operator !=(ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue>? left, ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue>? right) => !(left == right);

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return _dictionary.Aggregate(19, (h, i) => h * 19 + i.Key.GetHashCode() + (i.Value?.GetHashCode() ?? 0));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public static class ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEqualityEx
    {
        public static ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue> WithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue>(this ImmutableDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary) where TKey : notnull => new(dictionary);

        public static ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue> ToImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> list) where TKey : notnull => new(list.ToImmutableDictionary());
    }
}
```

### ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality JsonConverter

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace System.Collections.Immutable
{
    public class JsonConverterForImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEqualityFactory : JsonConverterFactory
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) =>
            typeToConvert.IsGenericType
            && typeToConvert.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<,>);

        public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            var keyType = typeToConvert.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            var valueType = typeToConvert.GetGenericArguments()[1];

            var dictionaryType = typeof(JsonConverterForImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<,>);

            var converter = (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(
                dictionaryType.MakeGenericType(keyType, valueType),
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
                binder: null,
                args: null,
                culture: null)!;

            return converter;
        }

        private class JsonConverterForImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue> : JsonConverter<ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue>> where TKey : notnull
        {
            public override ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
            {
                if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
                {
                    throw new JsonException();
                }

                reader.Read();

                Dictionary<TKey, TValue> elements = new();

                while (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
                {
                    var value = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>(ref reader, options);

                    elements.Add(value.Key, value.Value);

                    reader.Read();
                }

                return elements.ToImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality();
            }

            public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<TKey, TValue> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
            {
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value.AsEnumerable(), options);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### ImmutableDeepEqualityTests

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xunit;

namespace System.Collections.Immutable.Tests
{
    public class ImmutableDeepEqualityTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ArraysWithSameValues_AreConsideredEqual()
        {
            var array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }.ToImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality();
            var array1Copy = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }.ToImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality();

            Assert.Equal(array1, array1Copy);
            Assert.True(array1 == array1Copy);
            Assert.False(array1 != array1Copy);
            Assert.True(array1.Equals(array1Copy));
        }

        [Fact]
        public void ArraysWithDifferentValues_AreConsideredNotEqual()
        {
            var array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }.ToImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality();
            var array2 = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 }.ToImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality();

            Assert.NotEqual(array1, array2);
            Assert.False(array1 == array2);
            Assert.True(array1 != array2);
            Assert.False(array1.Equals(array2));
        }

        [Fact]
        public void DictionariesWithSameValues_AreConsideredEqual()
        {
            var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Key1", "1" }, { "Key2", "2" } }.ToImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality();
            var dict1Copy = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Key1", "1" }, { "Key2", "2" } }.ToImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality();

            Assert.Equal(dict1, dict1Copy);
            Assert.True(dict1 == dict1Copy);
            Assert.False(dict1 != dict1Copy);
            Assert.True(dict1.Equals(dict1Copy));
        }

        [Fact]
        public void DictionariesWithDifferentKeys_AreConsideredNotEqual()
        {
            var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Key1", "1" }, { "Key2", "2" } }.ToImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality();
            var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "KeyA", "1" }, { "KeyB", "2" } }.ToImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality();

            Assert.NotEqual(dict1, dict2);
            Assert.False(dict1 == dict2);
            Assert.True(dict1 != dict2);
            Assert.False(dict1.Equals(dict2));
        }

        [Fact]
        public void DictionariesWithDifferentValues_AreConsideredNotEqual()
        {
            var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Key1", "1" }, { "Key2", "2" } }.ToImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality();
            var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Key1", "A" }, { "Key2", "B" } }.ToImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality();

            Assert.NotEqual(dict1, dict2);
            Assert.False(dict1 == dict2);
            Assert.True(dict1 != dict2);
            Assert.False(dict1.Equals(dict2));
        }

        [Fact]
        public void RecordsUseDeepEquality()
        {
            var array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }.ToImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality();
            var array1Copy = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }.ToImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality();

            var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Key1", "1" }, { "Key2", "2" } }.ToImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality();
            var dict1Copy = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Key1", "1" }, { "Key2", "2" } }.ToImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality();

            var model1 = new TestModel(array1, dict1);
            var model1Copy = new TestModel(array1Copy, dict1Copy);

            Assert.Equal(model1, model1Copy);
            Assert.True(model1 == model1Copy);
            Assert.False(model1 != model1Copy);
            Assert.True(model1.Equals(model1Copy));
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Records_ThatUseDeepEquality_CanSerialize()
        {
            var array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }.ToImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality();

            var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Key1", "1" } }.ToImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality();

            var model1 = new TestModel(array1, dict1);

            var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(model1);

            Assert.Equal("{\"Ints\":[1,2,3],\"Dictionary\":[{\"Key\":\"Key1\",\"Value\":\"1\"}]}", json);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Records_ThatUseDeepEquality_CanDeserialize()
        {
            var json = "{\"Ints\":[1,2,3],\"Dictionary\":[{\"Key\":\"Key1\",\"Value\":\"1\"}]}";

            var modelFromJson = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestModel>(json);

            var array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }.ToImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality();

            var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Key1", "1" } }.ToImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality();

            var model1 = new TestModel(array1, dict1);

            Assert.Equal(model1, modelFromJson);
        }

        private sealed record TestModel(
            ImmutableArrayWithDeepEquality<int> Ints,
            ImmutableDictionaryWithDeepEquality<string, string> Dictionary);
    }
}
```

### Conclusion

As you can see it's no small task to implement, support, and maintain. After looking at are own needs we found deep equality was only needed to mask upstream issues that produced duplicate values when duplicate values never needed to be created in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

There is no out-of-the-box solution. You could try however derive out of
[Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1?view=net-5.0). Microsoft made it specifically for such cases where you do not want to create whole boilerplate (adding, removing etc.). You could use our approach to the same concept:
[ValueCollection.cs](https://github.com/nemesissoft/Nemesis.Essentials/blob/master/Nemesis.Essentials/Design/ValueCollection.cs)

Now it's also available via convenient [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nemesis.Essentials/1.1.0)

Answer (score 1):

This is an imperfect solution, but as long as you don't lie to yourself it can be useful.  You can create a record that inherits from IReadOnlyCollection or IReadOnlyList (or any of the other IReadOnly... interfaces).  However you will have to manually create several of the methods that records would make for you automatically (both for completeness and for the operations I expect you would want). This record type must be sealed, but otherwise is a straight forward implementation (EDIT: written quickly and untested):

```
public sealed record ReadOnlyListRecord<T> : IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    private readonly IReadOnlyList<T> _baseList;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or initializes the items in this collection.
    /// </summary>
    public IReadOnlyList<T> Items
    {
        get { return _baseList; }
        init { _baseList = value.ToList().AsReadOnly(); } 
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    [IgnoreMember]
    public int Count
    {
        get { return _baseList.Count; }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public T this[int index] => _baseList[index];

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int someHashValue = -234897289; 
        foreach(var item in _baseList)
        {
            someHashValue = someHashValue ^ item.GetHashCode();
        }

        return someHashValue;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public bool Equals(ReadOnlyListRecord<T> other) 
    {
        // create a proper equality method...
        if(other == null || other.Count != Count)
        {
            return false;
        }
        for(int i=0; i < Count;i++)
        {
            if(!other[i].Equals(this[i]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

However, I must caution you that it is VERY easy to lie with this type.  There is no guarantee that the items in the list are immutable, and that would break the assumptions that the overall record is immutable. A really bad example is if you make an instance of this record contain a list of normal mutable lists. BUT that is always true of records so just be careful and document that limitation well.

And the fact that this is sealed isn't that big of a problem. Generally I want another record to HAVE a list of values.  For example, in some engineering code, I want a record of something to have (among other things like names and other 1-off values) a list of coefficients, and I want the benefits of a list (not a fixed length, no extra slots, foreach...).  For primitives, strings, numbers, other immutable records, this will work well.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this today to use instead of an array.

I was using arrays as record elements already, then substituted-in `Values` instead of the array types.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Core
{
    // this JSON serializes like an array but implements value-equality semantics
    public class Values<T> where T : notnull
    {
        internal T[] Array { get; }

        public static implicit operator Values<T>?(T[]? array) => array == null ? null : new Values<T>(array);

        internal Values(T[] array)
        {
            Array = array;
        }

        internal int Length => Array.Length;

        public override bool Equals(object? obj)
        {
            Values<T>? rhs = obj as Values<T>;
            if (rhs == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return Array.SequenceEqual(rhs.Array);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-overriding-gethashcode
            int hash = 17;
            foreach (T item in Array)
            {
                hash = hash * 23 + item.GetHashCode();
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }

    // implementation of this class is copied from
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to
    public class JsonConverterFactoryForValuesOfT : JsonConverterFactory
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
        {
            return typeToConvert.IsGenericType && typeToConvert.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Values<>);
        }

        public override JsonConverter? CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            Type elementType = typeToConvert.GetGenericArguments()[0];

            JsonConverter converter = (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(
                typeof(JsonConverterForValuesOfT<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { elementType }),
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
                binder: null,
                args: null,
                culture: null)!;

            return converter;
        }
    }

    public class JsonConverterForValuesOfT<T> : JsonConverter<Values<T>> where T : notnull
    {
        public override Values<T>? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Values<T> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (T item in value.Array)
            {
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, item, options);
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a bit late to the question, however I want to add my solution to this problem (which does not require any new collection types added to the system).

My solution is to defined the record and in the body of the record to implement the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods to include the correct sematics.

A type coudld look like this.

```cs
public record Foo(ImmutableArray<int> Data)
{
    public virtual bool Equals(Foo? other)
    {
        if ((object)this == other)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if ((object?)other is null || EqualityContract != other.EqualityContract)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var comparer = StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer;
        return comparer.Equals(Data, other.Data);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var comparer = StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer;
        return (EqualityComparer<Type>.Default.GetHashCode(this.EqualityContract) * -1521134295)
            + comparer.GetHashCode(Data);
    }
}
```

Then the code

```cs
var f1 = new Foo(new[] { 1, }.ToImmutableArray());
var f2 = new Foo(new[] { 1, }.ToImmutableArray());
var f3 = new Foo(new[] { 1, 2, }.ToImmutableArray());

Console.WriteLine("f1 == f2: {0}", f1 == f2);
Console.WriteLine("f1 == f3: {0}", f1 == f3);
Console.WriteLine("f2 == f3: {0}", f2 == f3);

Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("f1 hashcode: {0}", f1.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine("f2 hashcode: {0}", f2.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine("f3 hashcode: {0}", f3.GetHashCode());

Console.WriteLine();
```

oututs

```
f1 == f2: True
f1 == f3: False
f2 == f3: False

f1 hashcode: 1105484886
f2 hashcode: 1105484886
f3 hashcode: -905789920
```

If one is not concerned about someone changing the array you can also define the type like

```cs
record Bar(int[] Arr)
{
    public virtual bool Equals(Bar other)
    {
        // no changes to previous example
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // no changes to previous example
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure how stable this solution is. It relies on the fact that the current compiler generated code will always at the end call the method `IEquatable<Foo>.Equals(Foo)`, if this would change it would break the code.

See [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G7cpIj) for an running example on dotnetfiddle and [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=) to checkout the compiler generated code.

Comment: Clever. But seems to defeat the goal of using a record? I mean, why not implement a regular class if you're still going to implement Equals & GetHashCode yourself?

Comment: You could then use this record as a base for another record and equality will still work. You also get some more things for free. Like the == and != operators.