# How to compare records containing collections of records without implementing equality comparisons

Tags: c#, .net, collections, pass-by-reference, c#-9.0

C# 9 introduces records, which among other benefits allow for really easy comparison. Is there some way I can take advantage of that functionality to compare a record composed of a collection of other records?

For example:

```
record Foo
{
    string Name {get; set;}
    List<Bar> Bars {get; set;}
    public Foo(string name, params int[] values)
    {
        Name = name;
        Bars = values.Select(v => new Bar(v)).ToList();
    }
}

record Bar
{
    int Value {get; set;}
    public Bar(int value) => Value = value;
}
```

Somewhere else in the code:

```
var foo1 = new Foo("Hi",1,2,3);
var foo2 = new Foo("Hi",1,2,3);

return foo1 == foo2; // I want this to return true
```

By the way I am **not** looking for a solution to this specific piece of code. I know I can override the `==` operator or implement `IComparable<Foo>`, etc. **My goal is to leverage built-in functionality so that I don't have to implement my own methods every time I want to compare a data container composed of a collection of data containers.** Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: "*Is there an easy way to do that*" is not the best choice of words, I mean we are all seasoned programmers here, most coding is easy.... There is no BCL one line (with no supporting code) way to to compare arbitrary collections of types. So I guess the answer is no. However there are ways, whether you consider them easy or not, `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @TheGeneral I edited it to say "_Is there a way to do that?_". Also, I'm not referring to comparing arbitrary collections of types. This question is only for record types

Comment: If you want `return foo1 == foo2;` _specifically_ to return true then it isn't possible given your constraints.

Comment: Are you willing to use inheritance? If so, consider implementing a generic implementation in the base class (that uses reflection to get the properties / fields etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found an ok solution. You can extend `List<T>` to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`

```
public class ValueEqualityList<T>:List<T>
{
    private readonly bool _requireMathcingOrder;
    public ValueEqualityList(bool requireMatchingOrder = false) => _requireMathcingOrder = requireMatchingOrder;

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (!(other is IEnumerable<T> enumerable)) return false;
        if(!_requireMathcingOrder)return enumerable.ScrambledEquals(this);
        return enumerable.SequenceEqual(this);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var hashCode = 0;
        foreach (var item in this)
        {
            hashCode ^= item.GetHashCode();
        }

        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

`Foo` becomes:

```
record Foo
{
    string Name {get; set;}
    List<Bar> Bars {get; set;}
    public Foo(string name, params int[] values)
    {
        Name = name;

        //this is the line that changed
        Bars = new ValueEqualityList<Bar>(values.Select(v => new Bar(v)));
    }
}
```

This uses some helper code:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns true if both enumerables contain the same items, regardless of order. O(N*Log(N))
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="first"></param>
    /// <param name="second"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool ScrambledEquals<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
    {
        var counts = first.GetCounts();

        foreach (var item in second)
        {
            if (!counts.TryGetValue(item, out var count)) return false;
            count -= 1;
            counts[item] = count;
            if (count < 0) return false;
        }

        return counts.Values.All(c => c == 0);
    }


    public static Dictionary<T, int> GetCounts<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {

        var counts = new Dictionary<T, int>();
        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            if (!counts.TryGetValue(item, out var count))
            {
                count = 0;
            }

            count++;
            counts[item] = count;
        }

        return counts;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no "nice" way to do what you want. You typically have one of two choices:

- Manually implement equality for your record, in this case using [`SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal) for the list, or
- only use classes that have value semantics.

For the latter you could write a wrapper class for list, e.g. as described in [this answer to "record types with collection properties & collections with value semantics"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64091408), and then only use that class in your records.